# Python - AttributeError - How to properly force use of existing exception

Tags: python, exception, attributeerror

I get the Error (obfuscated the path a little bit):

```
ERROR: (AttributeError) 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/nananana/nananana/batman.py", line 168, in main
    url = result.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

The code part is as follows:

```
result = re.search('(http.*?.+txt)',url)
url = result.group(1)
```

So, I get a line that contains an url. I try to extract the URL that starts with http ort https and ends on .txt with at least one character or - or _ or . in between.

The problem is that sometimes I get the above error. I assume it means that the re.search was unsuccessful.
Can I somehow ask if the result.group() is possible and if not let it run into one of my standard exception? The last part here being the key question.

```
except: 
  status = 'error'
  submitError2DB(db, fullurl, status, host, ip, txtname)
  print "\tAn unknown error occured. Fix needed.\nFailed.\n"
```

I only found the brilliant example to just do an:

```
raise Exception("I know python!")
```

but that's just not what I need.

Comment: It would be easier and simpler to just check if `result` is `None`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the result is not None like this

```
if result is not None:
    url = result.group(1)
else:
    raise Exception("No match")
```

In your words, if the result is not None, `result.group` is possible, otherwise an exception with text `No match` will be raised.

Comment: Brilliant! But how can I redirect it into my already existing exception and let it continue with the next msg (the next line to check for an URL)?